# curl not installed on DD-WRT version 3.0-r49567

Tags: dd-wrt, curl

Router: D-link DIR869
Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r49567 std (07/27/22)

Trying to use curl, but getting error when trying to run a script:

```
sh: eval: line 0: curl: not found
```

How do I install curl, and why isn't this already installed, I mean I have several routers with dd-wrt and curl was always installed.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[curl missing on TL-WDR4300, DD-WRT v24-sp2](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=321630&sid=d522d94b3fcdc196132361bb5d46705b)
has an answer (that I can't test).

The explanation is:

> BrainSlayer has removed a lot of features/packages to help save on space in favor of recent Q.O.S. code updates. 4mb and 8mb flash size routers were hit the hardest, but even on larger flash routers things are gone too. It's likely this package got removed to help save on space.

The final advice is :

> curl is available via (opkg) entware...ipkg is outdated install
> Entware first than:
>
> ```
> opkg install curl
> ```

I don't use DD-WRT myself, so can't help with further advice.

Comment: I know! But unfortunately:
> sh: eval: line 0: opkg: not found

-The same error.

Comment: It seems like you need to install [Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware) for it to become available.

Comment: But how would you do that from the router commandline without an installation tool installed exactly?

Comment: I had routers that could install from the computer when browsing to the firmware. Can't the sophisticated DD-WRT do the same?

Comment: I don't think so?